# 'Auth' does not contain a definition for 'SignIn' and no accessible extension method 'SignIn' accepting a first argument of type 'Auth'

Tags: c#, ios, firebase, xamarin, xamarin.ios

/*  'Auth' does not contain a definition for 'SignIn' and no accessible extension method 'SignIn' accepting a first argument of type 'Auth' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) Not sure If this has changed overtime or not. the error is in the line containing 
    '/*AppDataClass.auth.SignIn(inpEmail, inpPassword, async (user, error) =>*/' which is the third line from the top. i'm trying to make the sing in for my app work i've already done the registration part. i tried searching the firebase Docs but was not able to find anything similar, Do you guys think auth.SignInWithPassword work? instead of auth.SingnIn*/

```
 public static async Task Login(AppFeedView thisView, string inpEmail, string inpPassword)
    {
        bool done = false;

        AppDataClass.auth.SignIn(inpEmail, inpPassword, async (user, error) =>
        {
            if (error != null)
            {
                AlertShow.Alert(thisView, "Error", "The following Error has occured: " + 
 error.ToString());
                return;
            }

            UserClass newUser = new UserClass
            {
                Name = user.DisplayName,
                Uid = user.Uid,
                Email = user.Email
            };

            SetLocalUser.Set(newUser);


            await thisView.ReloadTableView();
            AlertShow.Alert(thisView, "Login Was Successful", "Welcome back " + newUser.Name);

            done = true;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

I installed `Xamarin.Firebase.iOS.Auth 6.2.1.1` and the login method should be:

```
   public static async void Login(string inpEmail, string inpPassword)
    {
        bool done = false;

        AuthDataResult AuthData = await Auth.DefaultInstance.SignInWithPasswordAsync(inpEmail, inpPassword);

        User user = AuthData.User;

        //do your own logic

    }
```

You can find the [FIRAuth#-signinwithemail:password:completion:](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Classes/FIRAuth#-signinwithemail:password:completion:) in the document.